# Read text file with AppleScript App in Xcode

Tags: xcode, applescript

I would like to read a text file in an AppleScript application in Xcode

```
set TextOfFile to read file "Macintosh HD:Users:myself:Desktop:Text.txt" using delimiter linefeed
set FirstText to item 1 of TextOfFile
log FirstText
```

Always thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

I wrote this code (above) and that successfully reads a text file in AppleScript, however when using the same code in my AppleScript app in Xcode it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a lot of cases if a regular AppleScript command is not understood, you can address the *current application* (note that getting the **paragraphs** will work with a variety of line endings):

```
tell current application to set textOfFile to paragraphs of (read file "Macintosh HD:Users:myself:Desktop:Text.txt")
set firstText to item 1 of textOfFile
log firstText
```

And if you are feeling adventurous, there are a variety of Cocoa methods available, such as:

```
set textOfFile to (current application's NSString's stringWithContentsOfFile:"/Users/myself/Desktop/Text.txt" encoding:(current application's NSUTF8StringEncoding) |error|:(missing value)) as text
set firstText to item 1 of paragraphs of textOfFile
log firstText
```